# Display comments from the most recent to the oldest in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to get all of the comments of the wordpress database related to a post, that I have decided that they have to be enabled and display them in the page, from the most recent to the oldest. These comments are a custom field with subfields. Is there a way to do this?

I've written the below code in the wordpress site up to now:

```
    $texts = get_post_meta($post->ID, "texts", true);

    if( $texts ) {
        for( $i = 0; $i < $texts; $i++ ) {
            $comment_text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'texts_' . $i . '_comment_text', true );
            $comment_displayed = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'texts_' . $i . '_comment_displayed', true);
            if ($comment_text && $comment_displayed) {
                $user = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'texts_' . $i . '_user', true );
                $user = getUserById($user);
                $text_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'texts_' . $i . '_text_date', true );
                echo $user->display_name;
                echo html_entity_decode($comment_text);
                echo $text_date;
                }
         }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works ?

```
function reverse_comments($comments,$id) {
    $comments = array_reverse($comments);
    return $comments;
}
add_filter('comments_array','reverse_comments',10,2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! These comments are a special custom field I have made in wordpress. I tried using array_reverse(), but $texts is not an array but a string, and even if I change true to false in get_post_meta it makes no difference, because $texts in 'for' loop behaves just like the number of iterations. I need 'for' loop to get the subfields...Is there another way?

Comment: Check if `explode() ` can be used to break those string to array, but I do not think It will work.

Comment: I thought about it too, but unfortunately there is no separator in the string, so I can't use the explode(). However thanks again for the help.

Comment: @simpleman91 Well then you'll have to change the way you store your comments. Why don't you just use the basic WP comments feature?

Comment: well, that 's a long story. I didn't make the site, I just try to make some corrections. These comments are a little bit different and they are related with another created post type not the default. Can I change the way they are stored now, only for this post type and without losing the information?